# How to test code that lights an Android device's LEDs?

Tags: android

How might I test code that lights up LEDs on an Android device? I do not have a device with LEDs.

```
notif.ledARGB = color.BLUE; 
notif.ledOnMS = 100;
notif.ledOffMS = 100;
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Answer (score 3):

As far I can tell there is no way to directly test LEDs in the emulator. The best you can do is ensure your notification is working properly and then assume that the LED is working as well. Maybe you could borrow a friend's device with an LED? If anyone else knows how to do this in the emulator, I'd love to know how!

Answer (score 1):

The android emulator *is* open source. If it doesn't currently support LEDs, you can look into adding support and submitting a patch.